# log4j 2 - is it possible to use multiple markers for one log message?

Tags: logging, filter, log4j2

I would like to do something like

```
logger.debug(new Marker[]{SQL_UPDATE,USER},"Updating user account");
```

Then I can filter either each SQL_UPDATE and/or each log regarding USER database.

Is it possible to achieve it somehow?

One solution would be to use specific log message for example I would use some specific text like @SQL_UP and then I would use text regex filter like:

```
<RegexFilter regex=".*@SQL_UP.*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
```

But I assume it would be slower and I would need to be careful to not have message text mixed with tags by mistake...

Comment: Separate code from question text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know log4j2 only allows a single marker to be applied per log message. However, markers can be given parent markers by calling the addParents method.

Ex. using defined markers DEALERSHIP_A, DEALERSHIP_B and PORSCHE

The following filter will log all messages about DEALERSHIP_A's PORSCHE

Java

`Marker DEALERSHIP_A, DEALERSHIP_B, PORSCHE;//must use MarkerManager.getMarker`

`PORSCHE.addParents(DEALERSHIP_A);//adds parents`

`logger.log(PORSCHE,"The 911 has maintenance issues");`

`PORSCE.setParents(DEALERSHIP_B);//replaces parents`

`logger.log(PORSCHE,"A cayenne has just been sold");`
`

Configuration File

`<filters>
   <MarkerFilter marker="DEALERSHIP_A" onMatch="Neutral" onMismatch="Deny"/>
   <MarkerFilter marker="PORSCHE" onMatch="Accept"  onMismatch="Deny"
</filters>`

Console Output with filter

`The 911 has maintenance issues`

Comment: Thx for answer. Still it is not enough for me. I wanted independent tags/markers. So I did my own class(es) while ago and I'm happy with it... I do not care about log4j2 anymore...